# Vue observable array lost on page refresh

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have a vue 2 project made with vue-cli. I'm trying to create a reactive array with vue observable like this:

**STORE.JS**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.observable({
 user_data: [],
});
```

So my idea is populate this array with user data comming from an axios call, like this:

**Login.vue**

```
import store from './utils/store'

self.$axios.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL+'users/me')
                .then(function (response){

                      store.user_data.info = response.data                   
                })
```

At this point everything is working fine, even if I import the store object in other component and print something like **store.user_data.info.name** it works. The problem comes when I refresh the page, throws this error:

**TypeError: *utils_store__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_8*_.default.user_data.info is undefined**

Any idea of what is the problem ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You defined `user_data` as empty array but you are using data as object. Also I'm not sure that you need `Vue.observable` in store.js. You should get data from actions and make update in mutations if it is pure vuejs project.

Comment: @J.Kovacevic thanks for trying to help. Your suggest says that I should use vuex ?...because I'm trying to avoid it...that's the idea of using an observable.

Comment: Ah I understand. Well if you need state across your application, vuex is way to go. If it is very small application, you can get away without it, but if your application will scale, I suggest you to try vuex.
About `user_data` issue, just initialize it as empty object if you are using it as object. :)